# Binding constant Collection to ComboBox & SelectedItem to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I'm new to MVVM in WPF and I have the following problem.

What I try to have is two ComboBoxes, each binding to the same `ObservableCollection<TwoProperties> DList` property as `ItemsSource` and with synchronized `SelectedItem`, so I wrote this in my XAML

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DList}" DisplayMemberPath="Property1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedD}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DList}" DisplayMemberPath="Property2" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedD}" />
```

with this viewmodel

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TwoProperties> _dList =
        new ObservableCollection<TwoProperties> {
             new TwoProperties(1,"one"),
             new TwoProperties(2,"two")
        };

    public ObservableCollection<TwoProperties> DList
    {
        get { return _dList; }
        set { _dList = value; OnPropertyChanged("DList"); }
    }

    private TwoProperties _selectedD;
    public TwoProperties SelectedD
    {
        get { return _selectedD; }
        set { _selectedD = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedD"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
public class TwoProperties
{
    public double Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public TwoProperties (double p1, string p2)
    {
        Property1 = p1;
        Property2 = p2;
    }
}
```

I would also like to have two TextBoxes that display the properties of the currently `SelectedItem` of the synchronized ComboBoxes. The properties `Property1` and `Property2` of `SelectedD` should be **editable**, however the `ObservableCollection<TwoProperties> _dList` **should remain constant/readonly and not change its values.**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedD.Property1}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedD.Property2}" />
```

But **when I edit the TextBoxes** and therefore SelectedD, also **_dList changes its values**, which is not what I want.

I hope I could explain my problem. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be implemented easily by changing the binding mode for the TextBoxes into one way as following:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedD.Property1,Mode=OneWay}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedD.Property2,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Thus when you change the textBox value, the changes would not be reflected back to the Observable collection objects.

Note that you can get rid of magical strings in your view model OnPropertyChanged by modifying the method as following:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

And then you can call it inside the setter of any property inside the view model without passing the name of the property as following:

```
    private TwoProperties _selectedD;
    public TwoProperties SelectedD
    {
        get { return _selectedD; }
        set { _selectedD = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Edit 2:
Update my binding and view model to get the edited values inside the view model

View model updates:

```
private double? editPropertyOne;
    public double? EditPropertyOne
    {
        get { return editPropertyOne; }
        set
        {
            editPropertyOne = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string editPropertyTwo;
    public string EditPropertyTwo
    {
        get { return editPropertyTwo; }
        set
        {
            editPropertyTwo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private TwoProperties _selectedD;
    public TwoProperties SelectedD
    {
        get { return _selectedD; }
        set
        {
            _selectedD = value; OnPropertyChanged();
            if (_selectedD != null)
            {
                EditPropertyOne = _selectedD.Property1;
                EditPropertyTwo = _selectedD.Property2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Xaml changes:

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding EditPropertyOne}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding EditPropertyTwo}" />
```

Comment: Great, thank you! However, changes in the TextBoxes will not be reflected in a property of the viewmodel with Model=OneWay, right? I would like to use the edited information of the TextBox in a property like selectedD. Or do I have to create a new property in the ViewModel that gets assigned and updated to SelectedD in the ComboBox every time the selection changes and bind it to the TextBox?

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, if you want to use the edited value, then you have to create new property inside your view model and updated it each time the selection change (please see the second edit of my answer)

Comment: Your solution works great. Now since my real class TwoProperties has more than just two properties but 72 and I am reluctant to  write a field/property pair in my viewmodel for every field/property pair in my real class, I was trying to change it and combine the two EditPropertyOne and EditPropertyTwo field/property pairs into one by having `private TwoProperties editProperty;` and `public TwoProperties { get ... set ...}`.  However then my _dList  gets overwritten with every change in the TextBoxes...  Now I am assuming I will have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in TwoProperties class.

Comment: If you where going to use TwoProperties with the UI related to it in one place then this would be an accepted solution, however if this scenario with the same view model classes and UI is exits in many places across your application then I recommend creating a custom control or user control and encapsulate your logic and data